# jQuery: using .val() to assign values to variables in an .each() loop?

Tags: jquery, each

Using jQuery, I am trying to create a form from which I take the entered values in each field and generate a table on submit.  For some reason, I can't seem to pass the correct variables.

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
 <ul id="pq_entry_1" class="clonedSection">
  <li><input id="name_1" name="name_1" value="name1" type="text" /></li>
  <li><input id="init_1" name="init_1" value="1" type="number" min="-100" max="100"/></li>
 </ul>

 <ul id="pq_entry_2" class="clonedSection">
  <li><input id="name_2" name="name_2" value="name2" type="text" /></li>
  <li><input id="init_2" name="init_2" value="1" type="number" min="-100" max="100"/></li>
 </ul>

 <ul id="pq_entry_3" class="clonedSection">
  <li><input id="name_3" name="name_3" value="name3" type="text" /></li>
  <li><input id="init_3" name="init_3" value="1" type="number" min="-100" max="100"/></li>
 </ul>
 <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<table>
 <thead>
  <th>Character</th>
  <th>Initiative</th>
 </thead>
     <tbody id="results">
     </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

And the jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        $('.clonedSection').each(function() {
            var stname = $('input[type=text]').val();
            var stinit = $('input[type=number]').val();
            $('#results').append('<tr><td>'+stname+'</td><td>'+stinit+'</td></tr>');
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

...and here it is in action, the way it's working now:  http://jsfiddle.net/KredH/

You can see that the expected behavior on "submit" would be to list all the field contents (by default, name1, name2, name3...) but instead, it only lists the contents from the first block.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to get the textbox without passing a context, hence `$('input[type=text]').val();` will always return you the same text in each iteration. Hence you are getting the same value appended.
Instead you can pass the the current `clonedSection` as the context for the jquery selector (`this` refers to current `clonedSection` in the loop) ;

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        $('.clonedSection').each(function() {
            var stname = $('input[type=text]', this).val(); //Notice the change here
            var stinit = $('input[type=number]', this).val(); //Notice the change here
            $('#results').append('<tr><td>'+stname+'</td><td>'+stinit+'</td></tr>');
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KredH/1/